# how to use values in dictionary in sub process

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, subprocess

my_dict is dictionary have values

sample value :

```
{0: {'Id': 'd1', 'name': 'elpato', 'email': '122as@gmail.com'}, 1: {'Id': 'd2', 'name': 'petoka', 'email': 'sss@gmail.com'}}
```

how to use name key in loop of subprocess so that it runs till count of name ends in a loop one by one.

example :

```
 subprocess.call(["...",name])
```

here name should be in loop using values of dict name, so here it should loop and call the subprocess two times i.e,. elpato and petoka.  in case of dict having 1000 values it should loop 1000 times

Comment: Use a `for` loop iterating through the dictionary?

Comment: can you elaborate it more

Comment: @elmantospetus https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 1):

As Green Cloak Guy suggested, we can use a for loop

```
myDict = {0: {'Id': 'd1', 'name': 'elpato', 'email': '122as@gmail.com'}, 1: {'Id': 'd2', 'name': 'petoka', 'email': 'sss@gmail.com'}}
for key in myDict:
    print(myDict[key]['name'])
```

Comment: how to use them in subprocess ?

Comment: myDict[key]['name'] gives you the names you asked for, so based on your code... subprocess.call(["...",myDict[key]['name']])

Answer (score 1):

```
myDict = {0: {'Id': 'd1', 'name': 'elpato', 'email': '122as@gmail.com'}, 1: {'Id': 'd2', 'name': 'petoka', 'email': 'sss@gmail.com'}}
for name in [v['name'] for v in myDict.values()]:
    #subprocess.call(["...", name])
    print(name)
```

output

```
elpato
petoka
```